# execute php code within string

Tags: php, echo, inline-code

This question is just for me to learn from.  I can easily resolve it outside of the echo...but there MUST be a way to perform a basic calculation or function call within an echo statement...right?

```
$CurrentMembershipYear = '2016';

echo '<h2>Two-Year Membership for '.$CurrentMembershipYear.' and '.intval($CurrentMembershipYear)+1.'</h2>';
```

This should be echoing "**Two-Year Membership for 2016 and 2017**" but instead is generating errors.  Usually I would just pre-calculate the second value before the echo statement and just pass it as a variable...but surely there is a way to put this calculation inline?

Comment: Put some parentheses around it. (Look up operator precedence for more info)

Comment: thanks @Rizier123...I figured it out right after I had given up and posted...  but yes... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind...bone-headed brain asleep.  Just needed parenthesis...I had only tried curvy braces:

```
$CurrentMembershipYear = '2016';

echo '<h2>Two-Year Membership for '.$CurrentMembershipYear.' and '.(intval($CurrentMembershipYear)+1).'</h2>';
```

Comment: side note, you dont need intval

Comment: I added that because my numeric year is actually stored as a string not a number...so I thought that might have been the issue initially.  I will give it a test without the intval and see what happens.  Thanks.

Comment: its php, its loosely typed, so things like that work (they wouldn't in other languages)

Answer (score 0):

parenthesis should solve it

```
(intval($CurrentMembershipYear)+1)
```

Comment: *parenthesis should solve it* yes, if you place them right.